# Unable to create 4.2.2 Android Emulator in the AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-virtual-device

**Edit**

This question was marked as duplicate. I thought I had a unique - or more unique than most - issue as it didn't matter what I did, pressing 'OK' wouldn't work.

Its all irrelevant now as I have got rid of Eclipse and am now using Android Studio.

Its seems a great IDE so far, its based on intelliJ and as you would expect, geared totally towards Android.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

***Question Background:***

I have recently updated and installed my Android SDK for version 4.2.2(API 17) to Android 1.5(API 3):

[image]

***The issue:***

I am now trying to add a new Nexus 4 emulator in the following way:

[image]

**It dosent matter what combination of parameters I use, clicking 'OK' does nothing**

I've seen a number of people talking about not having the ARM EABI V7a system image, but as shown I have this installed:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can solve this frustrating issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not answer how to do it the way *you* want to but I can highly recommend

[Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Where you are not going to have this problem.